# SQL Query to get sums among multiple payments which are greater than or less than 10k

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to write a query to get sums of payments from accounts for a month. I have been able to get it for the most part but I have hit a road block. My challenge is that I need a count of the amount of payments that are either < 10000 or => 10000. The business rules are that a single payment may not exceed 10000 but there can be multiple payments made that can total more than 10000. As a simple mock database it might look like

```
ID | AccountNo | Payment
1  | 1         | 5000
2  | 1         | 6000
3  | 2         | 5000
4  | 3         | 9000
5  | 3         | 5000
```

So the results I would expect would be something like

```
NumberOfPaymentsBelow10K | NumberOfPayments10K+
1                        | 2
```

I would like to avoid doing a function or stored procedure and would prefer a sub query.

Any help with this query would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by `The business rules are that a single payment may not exceed 10000`?

Comment: Originally I just had two queries, one did a count of the paymentamounts => 10000 and another query that did a count of payments < 10000. Then I discovered the business rules indicating that a single payment cannot exceed 10000. So now I need to get a count of the sum of payments that are either below 10k or 10k + since I am not just looking at a single payment, I am looking across multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest avoiding sub-queries as much as possible because it hits the performance, specially if you have a huge amount of data, so, you can use something like `Common Table Expression` instead. You can do the same by using:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT AccountNo, SUM(Payment) AS TotalPayment
    FROM Payments
    GROUP BY AccountNo
)

SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN TotalPayment < 10000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'NumberOfPaymentsBelow10K',
    SUM(CASE WHEN TotalPayment >= 10000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'NumberOfPayments10K+'
FROM CTE
```

Comment: The WITH clause is a way of writing a subquery. It is just a different way of writing it. And it is simply not true that subqueries are bad performance. You _may_ have a performance impact if a subquery is executed in a nested loop but that is clearly not the case here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I was just talking generally. I know that both CTE and SubQuery are, in theory, the same as both provide the same info to the query optimizer. But, I prefer CTE as it could be easily identified and calculated once, then you can reuse.

Comment: This provided me with what I was looking for. Though I was a little vague with my requirements because I already had some of the query built I just used this logic and separated it into two queries. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the totals per account using SUM and GROUP BY...

```
SELECT AccountNo, SUM(Payment) AS TotPay
FROM payments
GROUP BY AccountNo
```

You can use that result to count the number over 10000

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT AccountNo, SUM(Payment) AS TotPay
    FROM payments
    GROUP BY AccountNo
)
WHERE TotPay>10000
```

You can get the the number over and the number under in a single query if you want but that's a but more complicated:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(CASE WHEN TotPay<=10000 THEN 1 END) AS Below10K,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN TotPay> 10000 THEN 1 END) AS Above10K
FROM (
    SELECT AccountNo, SUM(Payment) AS TotPay
    FROM payments
    GROUP BY AccountNo
)
```

Comment: SUM works fine, but I suppose COUNT is clearer. ELSE 0 is redundant as the default NULL values delivers what is required.

Comment: As I am sure this would have worked, I got errors in my query where it said Totpay was not a column. Maybe I had to use an alias or something?